# Select from table name defined in a loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 database connections: `a` and `b` where they both share the same schema but not necessarily the same data. I need to check both database's total number of rows for each table using a loop and compare their counts. 
Using a nested table collection, my attempt so far:

```
DECLARE  
    TYPE nt_rows IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    nt_rows1 nt_num := nt_num();
    nt_rows2 nt_num := nt_num();
    counter INT := 0;

    CURSOR c_tables1 IS 
        SELECT TABLE_NAME
        FROM ALL_TABLES
        WHERE OWNER IN ('a')
        ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC;

    CURSOR c_tables2 IS
        SELECT TABLE_NAME
        FROM ALL_TABLES
        WHERE OWNER IN ('b')
        ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC;
```

BEGIN block: loop through each cursor and add them to each array

```
BEGIN
    FOR i IN c_tables1 LOOP  
        nt_rows1.extend;
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a.i.TABLE_NAME INTO nt_rows1(counter);
    END LOOP;
```

The last line does not work where 'a' is the database connection name and i is index of each table_name. 
I also tried:

```
nt_rows1(counter) := SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a.i.TABLE_NAME;
```

and it also doesn't work, any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: When you say it "does not work", exactly what do you mean?  Do you get a compiler error?  Does the code raise an exception at runtime?  Does your code run but give you the wrong output (and if so, what output do you get and what output are you hoping for it to give you)?

Comment: When I meant it doesn't work, it does not insert the COUNT(*) to the nested table. The output showed an invalid table name

Comment: It's `select x into y from z`, not `select x from z into y` (as in your first example) or `y := select x from z` (as in your last example). However, PL/SQL compiles using the actual table names as they appear in the code. There's no implicit runtime substitution of variables for table names. You'd need to code dynamic SQL for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query data from a table whose name is in a string (for example a local variable or a cursor field) and hence not known at compile time, you will need to use dynamic SQL.

Try replacing the line

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a.i.TABLE_NAME INTO nt_rows1(counter);
```

with

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a.' || i.TABLE_NAME INTO nt_rows1(counter);
```

Note also that your code is not incrementing the `counter` variable.  Since you are starting with `counter` set to `0`, and `0` isn't a valid index into a nested table, I would recommend adding a line to increment `counter` before the line above.